# HTTP Response: Google misplaced the content-length

Tags: http, httpresponse, http-response-codes

When receiving a raw response from `http://www.google.com/` the `Content-Length` header is missing. Instead the number of bytes to receive is placed after the end of header code `\r\n\r\n` but before the actual content.

I looked at the raw response and the `8000` contains `\r\n` for an end of line.

## Partial Google Response

## Header

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 28 Oct 2014 18:38:37 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Set-Cookie: ...
Set-Cookie: ...
P3P: ...
Server: gws
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic,p=0.01
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

## End of Header (signified by '\r\n\r\n')

```
8000     # has '\r\n', I am assuming this is the content-length?

<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="en"><head><meta content...`
```

## End Response

So my question is why is Google so damn special, that they can screw up my re-invention of the HTTP wheel. And if I should account for this happening in all my responses or just from Google.

Comment: You might do a little research before making accusations. Ironically, the first result of Googling `content-length missing` provides a clue to the answer. Also, if you're "reinventing the HTTP wheel," you should be doing everything you can to learn about standard HTTP headers (anything that doesn't start with an "X-"); if you had been curious about the `Transfer-Encoding` header, you would also have found your answer that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should account for this possibility from all responses, as it is quite common. Nothing about this is "special" and this is indeed completely legitimate behavior.

What you're assuming is the content-length is actually the chunk size, as per the [Chunked Transfer Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) that the server is responding with.

The response is complete when a chunk size of 0 is encountered, thus the effective content-length of a chunked response is equal to the sum of chunk sizes.

This has been part of the HTTP spec since 1999.

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me